# Is there way to access animation-nodes attribute in object-material with OSL script?

Tags: materials, animation-nodes, osl

In this example, I have assigned a velocity attribute with animation nodes and then trying to access the velocity attribute with OSL script in object-material. But it is not working, why ???
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think Blender allows such use of properties, see [Add custom object properties as usable attributes](https://developer.blender.org/D2057). For alternative methods. See the *Coloring Objects* section of this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101299/render-100k-objects-each-with-independent-color-and-scale-through-time).

Comment: Thanks @OmarAhmad. Yeah, I'm using vertex color to transfer data from animation nodes to object-material, but it is not very efficient for large number of objects.

Comment: @3DSingh The answer I linked include an approach that is much more efficient than vertex colors. See the Object Index section of the answer.